# Print other language character in csv using perl file handling

Tags: perl, csv, unicode, file-handling

I am scraping a site based on German language , I am trying to store the content of the site in a CSV using Perl , but i am facing garbage value in the csv, the code i use is

```
    open my $fh, '>> :encoding(UTF-8)', 'output.csv';
    print {$fh} qq|"$title"\n|;
    close $fh;
```

For example :I expect **Weiß  ,Römersandalen**  , but i get **WeiÃŸ, RÃ¶mersandalen**

**Update :**

Code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
use autodie qw(:all);
my $m = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();


print "\n\n *******Program Begins********\n\n";

$m->get($url) or die "unable to get $url";
my $Home_Con=$m->content;
my $title='';


if($Home_Con=~m/<span id="btAsinTitle">([^<]*?)<\/span>/is){
$title=$1;
print "title ::$1\n";
}
open my $fh, '>> :encoding(UTF-8)', 's.txt';      #<= (Weiß)
print {$fh} qq|"$title"\n|;
close $fh;

open $fh, '>> :encoding(UTF-8)', 's1.csv';      #<= (WeiÃŸ)

print {$fh} qq|"$title"\n|;
close $fh;

    print "\n\n *******Program ends********";
            <>;
```

This is the part of code. The method works fine in text files, but not in csv.

Comment: [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html) documentation

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18398570/edit) to provide the output of `use Devel::Peek qw(Dump); Dump $title;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've shown us the code where you're encoding the data correctly as you write it to the file.

What we also need to see is how the data gets into your program. Are you decoding it correctly at that point?

**Update:**

If the code was really just `my $title='Weiß ,Römersandalen'` as you say in the comments, then the solution would be as simple as adding `use utf8` to your code.

The point is that Perl needs to know how to interpret the stream of bytes that it's dealing with. Outside your program, data exists as bytes in various encodings. You need to decode that data as it enters your program (decoding turns a stream of bytes into a string of characters) and encode it again as it leaves your program. You're doing the encoding step correctly, but not the decoding step.

The reason that `use utf8` fixes that in the simple example you've given is that `use utf8` tells Perl that your source code should be interpreted as a stream of bytes encoded as utf8. It then converts that stream of bytes into a string of characters containing the correct characters for 'Weiß ,Römersandalen'. It can then successfully encode those characters into bytes representing those characters encoded as utf8 as they are written to the file.

Your data is actually coming from a web page. I assume you're using LWP::Simple or something like that. That data might be encoded as utf8 (I doubt it, given the problems you're having) but it might also be encoded as ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-9 or CP1252 or any number of other encodings. Unless you know what the encoding is and correctly decode the incoming data, you will see the results that you are getting.

Comment: :Thanks Dave. Lets say this is the code `my $title='Weiß ,Römersandalen'; open my $fh, '>> :encoding(UTF-8)', 'output.csv';
    print {$fh} qq|"$title"\n|;
    close $fh;`

Comment: But that's not the code. You say you are scraping the data from a web site. How the data enters your program is just as important as how it leaves.

Comment: Wonderful Explanation Dave, Thank you so much. the site was based on "iso-8859-15", i have just turned the UTC-8 to iso-8859-15. it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Check if there are any weird characters at start or anywhere in the file using commands like *head* or *tail*